# How to compare two tables with composite-key located in different systems (BigQuery and MySQL)?

Tags: mysql, database, google-bigquery

I must update BigQuery tables with rows from MySQL tables in daily basis. Usually, I compare the max ID in both databases and get the different rows. For example, I have TableBQ in BigQuery and TableM in Mysql and they have the same schema (columns with same name and data type). When I do a 'SELECT MAX(ID) from', I get 1005 from TableM and 1003 from TableBQ, I conclude the TableBQ is out-of-date then I send to TableBQ only rows with IDs bigger than 1003. This works just fine with primary key tables, but I need to update composite-key tables too.

Today I see two solutions:

1) the worst: insert the whole table (which may already have 16 millions of rows) everyday to BigQuery

2) not so bad, but avoidable: create an primary key and make the table work like the others

In my case, I have to work with two composite-key tables and one of them was created by Wordpress: [wp_term_relationships](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_term_relationships)

Answer (score 1):

you may consider to use **surrogate key** for your data.

In your case, your table structure has Composite Key (Natural Key). If you can alter your table, I suggest you to add **Sequential Surrogate Key** to your table which has no meaning for business but necessary for data movement, and create index for it.

you can

```
ALTER TABLE `mytable` ADD `rowId` INT(8) UNIQUE NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST;
```

then you can use this column to identify data which is needed to be moved to your target DB